# Model not updating correct

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I update my database row. It for some reason update all the values as the same as last input which is very strange.

**How can I get it working so all rows do not get updated with the value all the same?**

This is how my database works. 
    $group = 'config'.
    $key = example:'config_name'.
    $value = what ever is typed in $key.

In my model I use `foreach ($data as $key => $value) {` It is very strange that it updates all values with the last input value.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_website_setting extends CI_Model {

    public function editWebsite($group , $data, $website_id = 0) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            // Make sure only keys belonging to this group are used
            if (substr($key, 0, strlen($group)) == $group) {
                if (!is_array($value)) {
                $this->db->set('group', $group);
                $this->db->set('value', $key);
                $this->db->set('value', $value);
                $this->db->set('website_id', $website_id);
                $this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'setting');
                } else {
                $this->db->set('group', $group);
                $this->db->set('value', $key);
                $this->db->set('value', $value);
                $this->db->set('website_id', $website_id);
                $this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'setting');
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Website_settings extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->lang->load('admin/setting/setting', 'english');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->document->setTitle($this->lang->line('heading_title'));

        $data['entry_name'] = $this->lang->line('entry_name');
        $data['entry_owner'] = $this->lang->line('entry_owner');

        if (!empty($this->input->post('config_name'))) {
            $data['config_name'] = $this->input->post('config_name');
        } else {
            $data['config_name'] = $this->settings->get('config_name');
        }

        if (!empty($this->input->post('config_owner'))) {
            $data['config_owner'] = $this->input->post('config_owner');
        } else {
            $data['config_owner'] = $this->settings->get('config_owner');
        }

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('config_name', 'Website Name');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('config_owner', 'Your Name');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            return $this->load->view('setting/website_settings', $data);

        } else {

            $this->load->model('admin/setting/model_website_setting');

            $this->model_website_setting->editWebsite('config', $this->input->post());

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You have updated settings!');

            redirect('admin/setting/website');
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: why are you setting the `value` column twice?

Comment: Was just testing it out if use it once same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i were you i would use the built in `update_batch` and will not place an `update` on every loop.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    // Make sure only keys belonging to this group are used
    if (substr($key, 0, strlen($group)) == $group) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
        // this is where you do the logic
        // if the value is the same do not insert in the update array
        // if the value is not the same then insert it on the update array
            $update[]  = array(
                'group' => $group,
                'value' => $key,
                'website_id' => $website_id 
            );

        } else {

            $update[]  = array(
                'group' => $group,
                'value' => $key,
                'website_id' => $website_id 
            );
        }


    }
}

$this->db->update_batch($this->db->dbprefix . 'setting', $update , 'website_id');
```

sample on how to use update batch on your code not tested.